# convert old delphi 5 project to diagrams (also vb6)

Tags: delphi, vb6

Does anyone know of any (free) tools that will convert an old Delhi 5 project into class diagrams / uml or any form of diagrams for ease of reading?

Also, if you know of any VB6 tools (again, preferably free) that would also convert to some form of diagrams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No tool will beat [ModelMaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com)  (Not free)

for free one try [ESS Model](http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source project and will work Delphi code (It's written by Delphi BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but [Modelmaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/) does the job for Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Turbo Delphi Explorer is free, can open Delphi 5 projects and contains a Model View (Together) which allows to drag and drop classes to diagrams in the Delphi IDE, with automatic connections for class inheritance.

As always when using tools which work on your precious code, do not remember to use backups or source control.

Comment: (but it can't open projects with custom components, which makes it of limited use for this)

Comment: Custom components can not be installed in the free Explorer editions - but is it also impossible to open and compile the project (without opening forms) if I add all source paths to the library path?

Answer (score 0):

For VB, take a look at [Visual UML](http://www.visualuml.com/).
And for both Delphi and VB, [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/features.html) is a good choice.
(Both of them aren't free, there is NO free one for VB, AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Use a commercial tool called convertTo to convert you Delphi forms to VB Forms. It will not convert Delhi code to VB though. You will have to do that by hand.

I am interested to know as to why you want to move from Delphi to VB6 (classic)?

Comment: I am trying to document the delphi code and thought it would be easier to read if i converted the classes into diagrams.  I dont want to convert into vb? I was asking if there are also any VB to diagram tools available also?